# How to prove algebraic theorem of the solution set of the equation ax+b=c using field axioms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

Prove the following Theorem: If a, b, c are numbers, the solution set of the
equation ax + b = c consists of either (a) a single number, (b) the empty set,
or (c) the entire real line. Hint: If you are surprised to see cases (b) and (c),
it’s probably because you are assuming, unconsciously, that a is not equal to 0.

Can someone help me prove this using field axioms? I think I may have done the first one, with one solution, using additive inverse to get x= c-b/a. Is that correct? How do I begin to solve for part b and c? I can set a =0 i think, but then what? Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

So, you have seen for (a) that if $a \ne 0$, we have a single solution, namely $x = a^{-1}(c-b)$. Hence, we are left with the case $a = 0$, that is with the equation $$ 0x + b = c \tag 1 $$
As, in fields, we have $0x = 0$ for any $x$ - which can be seen as follows: 
\begin{align*}
  0x &= (0+0)x & \text{$0$ is additive unit}\\
     &= 0x + 0x &\text{distributivity}\\
 \iff 0 &= 0x   &\text{add $-0x$ on both sides}
\end{align*}
we may rewrite (1) as 
$$ b = c \tag{1'} $$
If now $b=c$, we have, that (c), all elements of our field are solutions to (1), if $b\ne c$, then (b), no solution of (1) exists.

Comment: So, If I am understanding correctly: (b) the empty set would be written out like this : ax+b=c, where a=0 and b is NOT equal to c, we have, ax+b=0--> 0x+b=c given--> 0+b=c by theorem a(0)=0 --> 0-0+b=c-0 by additive inverse --> b=c-0 simplify --> b does NOT =0 does writing it out like this make sense?